# display text depending on possibilities

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I have 6 values. out which user can selects any of those values.  Out of that 6 values 3 are withplans and 3 are withoutplans. According to user selected values I have to show links like below:

1. withplan link1
2. withplan link2
3. withplan link3

OR

4. withoutplan link4
5. withoutplan link5
6. withoutplan link6

I have made three arrays :
$userSelected , $targetWith , $targetWithout

```
 $targetWith = array('val1', 'val2', 'val3'); 

    $targetWithout = array('val4', 'val5', 'val6');
```

There are 3 possibilities in user selection.

**Possibility 1:** User can select one from with and one from without(`$userSelected = array('val1','val4');`), so that time OR will show.

**Possibility 2:** If user selects only withplans(`$userSelected = array('val1','val2');`) then OR should not be shown.

**Possibility 3:** if user selects only withoutplans(`$userSelected = array('val5','val6');`) then OR should not be shown.

To display OR I have used `array_intersect` but that is not working as expected. If user selects only with plans then OR is getting displayed.

```
  if( (count(array_intersect($userSelected , $targetWith)) != count($targetWith)) || (count(array_intersect($userSelected , $targetWithout)) != count($targetWithout))){
    // all of $target not is in $userSelected 
  
       echo   '<p><strong>-Or-</strong></p>';
}
```

I have also tried

```
if((count(array_intersect($userSelected , $targetWith)) > 0) || (count(array_intersect($userSelected , $targetWithout)) > 0)){
     // at least one of $target is in $userSelected 
 
        echo  '<p><strong>-Or-</strong></p>';
}
```

Using both above codes, OR is getting displayed for 2,3 possibilities. which should be shown.

I am not getting whats going wrong. How should be that code? If there is any other way to achieve that possibilities please suggest. Please help and guide. thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want _OR_ to display if the user's selection is found within both `$targetWith` and `$targetWithout` and everything else should not display _OR_?

Comment: @waterloomatt yes. if one of the withplans or one of the withoutplans is found in user's selection then only display OR. Other will not need OR to be displayed

Comment: How many values can a user select? Is there a min/max?

Comment: @waterloomatt user can select min 0 and max 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to determine if the user's selection(s) are present in both arrays, you can simply use `array_intersect` twice to check that.

```
<?php

// Ex. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/248e7414d6a3fdbb2555ac206455a7fa2e894561

$with = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'];
$without = ['val4', 'val5', 'val6'];

$userSelections = ['val1', 'val6'];

$inBoth = 
    !empty(array_intersect($userSelections, $with)) && 
    !empty(array_intersect($userSelections, $without));

if ($inBoth) {
    echo '<p><strong>-Or-</strong></p>';
}
```